# Deploy a c++ application, what redistributables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to deploy/run a c++ program compiled with visual studio 2017 in a new server (windows server 2016).

I have installed the redistributables for Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable x86/x64.

It still doesn't work.

However if I install the Windows 10 SDK (on windows server 2016) it works.

Is there a smaller package that I can install?

-Gina

Comment: Sounds like you installed the wrong redistributable, or your app has other dependencies not covered by the redistributable. Is there a reason why you are compiling your app to require external dependencies to begin with?

Comment: It is a third party app that I am just using their make file to compile it. I don't think I have a wrong redist, just missing the correct redist.

Comment: Use ``Dependency Walker`` to find out what's missing: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: I tried Dependency Walker and nothing came up. I will post the results in case I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You may need Windows API stub DLLs, it located in windows SDK folder, e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs`

You must use the correct version dependents on your target Windows version and your application version.